# NSMutableArray remove object 1 before last object

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsmutablearray

I have many `UIImageView` in an `NSMuatableArray` and I need to remove a certain `UIImageView` from the view, but I think that if I release the `UIImageView` it will still be in the array.

I don't want that, but there is a little problem. The `UIImageView` that I need to remove is exactly 1 object before the last object in the array, so I can't use `removeLastObject`. I do know the tag number, but I can't write it like this because I would change the array while using it.

```
for (UIImageView *k in array1) {
    if (k.tag==tagzahl-1) {
       if (x==1){
          [k removeFromSuperview];
          [array1 remove object:k];
       }
    }
}
```

I am using: `[array1 addObject:myimage];` to add the `UIImageView`s to the array, so I do not know the index.

Comment: the problems is you can not removeObject from an NSArray while iterating over it like that. if you want to keep the loop as is then you should keep a pointer to the object you want to remove, and remove it after finishing the iteration.. though the best approach would be to not iterate over them at all and get immediate reference to it. Paul.s & trojanfoe answers do exactly that in two different ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that tag which you say you do then

```
UIView *view = [viewContainingImageView viewWithTag:tagzahl-1];
[view removeFromSuperview];
[array1 removeObject:view];
```

Comment: there is no funktion called viewContainingImageView viewWithTag:

Comment: Nope this should be replaced by a pointer to the view that actually contains the image view.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([array1 count] >= 2)
{
    NSUInteger index = [array1 count] - 2;
    UIImageView *view = [array1 objectAtIndex:index];
    [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```